# Zend_Auth Identity not persisting between controllers

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, identity, zend-auth

Fairly new to Zend Framework 1.11 with Doctrine 2.

I have successfully created a login etc using Doctrine.

My current problem though is that the Zend_Auth instance works fine when I stay within the controller that the log in is within.

If I try determine the state of Zend_Auth::getInstance->HasIdentity() in any other controller it returns blank.

If I then go back to any page residing within the controller containing the login/authentication hasIdentity works fine.

I have even tried writing to the storage but this provides no joy.

My auth code is as follows which is the action called after clicking Login (Within MembersareaController)

```
public function authAction()
{
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    $loginForm = new Application_Model_Login();

    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        $usr = "";
        $pwd = "";
        $KeepLoggedIn = false;
        $message = "";

        $usr = $this->_getParam('username'); 
        $pwd = $this->_getParam('password');
        $pwdMd5 = md5($pwd);

        if($usr !== "" && $pwd !== ""){

            $GDSAdaptor = new ZC_Auth_Adapter($usr, $pwdMd5);

            $result = \Zend_Auth::getInstance()->authenticate($GDSAdaptor);

            if(\Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()){
                $this->flashMessenger->addMessage(LOGIN_SUCCESS);
                $this->_redirect('/membersarea/index');
            }else{
                $this->flashMessenger->addMessage(LOGIN_INVALID);
            }
        }else{
            $this->flashMessenger->addMessage(LOGIN_MISSING_FORMVAL);
            $this->_redirect('/membersarea/login');
        }
    }
```

Trying to seeing a person is logged in on the IndexController with the following code produces no results. hasIdentity returns a blank value.

```
public function indexAction()
{

    if(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity())
    {
        $msg = "hasIdentity: YES";
    }else{
        $msg = "hasIdentity: NO";
    }

    $this->view->msg = $msg;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the cookie for your PHP session is set to the proper domain? I think you should verify using firebug

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply.

I've compared the cookie info using Firebug between the two and the cookie info is identical.

Comment: I have noticed that there are two seperate cookies for the domain with differing PHPSESSION ids and the paths are different. One has the path set to '/membersarea' which is the controller with the auth stuff on and the second is set to '/' which is the homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend_Session::rememberMe(); in the bootstrap solved this issue